# Outdoor CPE as a solution to my WIFI needs

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a house in a 7k sqft area, out of which 3k sqft has a two-storied construction. There is also an outhouse which I use as a theatre. I have a good fibber internet connection of 200 MBPS. This works well around the router which is on the second floor. I get little to no connectivity in the outhouse and the garden. The network is always choppy even on the first floor.

I am looking for options so that I should be able to roam seamlessly inside my house without losing internet connection.

One solution I found was installing an outdoor CPE. This looks so promising. from the reviews I feel very confident I would get internet in the garden, terrace, and other open spaces. But I am not sure If I would get good connectivity inside the house. This is the specific one I am planning to buy [link](https://www.tp-link.com/in/business-networking/outdoor-radio/cpe220/)

Does anyone have experience or knowledge about whether this is the right solution or not?

I have researched into simple wifi range extenders but I saw so many mixed reviews, people complaining about getting only 20% speed, frequent need to restart, and what not.

I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: A CPE is a Customer Premises Equipement, it is the customer-side device of a communications link (here a wireless link directly from a wireless ISP), like the modem or router when connected via DSL, cable, or fibre. It is most definitely not what you are looking for. You should probably look into WiFi mesh solutions and/or CPL-based solutions, but to cover 700 m2 you can expect to need quite a few devices to have good coverage throughout.

Comment: The best setup is enough access points (APs) to cover everywhere you want to be, connected by a wired LAN backbone. That's for example what hotels use. You need to bridge the AP with the LAN backbone, which isn't easy on consumer routers, but can be made to work by installing open firmware like OpenWRT (if the hardware is supported). I'd advise against extenders, unless they are LAN connected.